# Some problems with positioning on MSE

Tags: bug, design

Some elements are not well positioned on MSE. For example, on the review stats page:

[image]

The panel where you can see badge progress is gone, but if you scroll to the bottom of the page, then you see it there:

[image]

The same problem for the 404 page:

[image]

The "404" image should be next to the links, but it is below the links.